# Select "N" consecutive groups of "X" records

Tags: sql-server

I need to filter "N" consecutive groups of "X" records from a list like this:

```
1
4
5
6
9
12
```

In the sample list the consecutive groups of "X" records when X=2 are:

```
4,5
5,6
```

Is there a way, using SQL Server 2008 window functions to get that result?.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
DECLARE @x int = 2;

WITH 
  consecutive_groups (n, grp) AS (
    SELECT n, n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
    FROM NumbersTable
  ),
  groups_with_minmax (n, grp, nMin, nMax) AS (
    SELECT n, grp
      , MIN(n) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
      , MAX(n) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
    FROM consecutive_groups
  )
SELECT n AS SequenceStart, n+@x-1 AS SequenceEnd
FROM groups_with_minmax
WHERE n+@x-1 BETWEEN nMin AND nMax;
```

All of the window functions used should be available in SQL Server 2008.